# Javascript Runtime error

Tags: javascript

why i am getting runtime error in javascript at

> var ClientID = document.getElementById("ClientIDTextBox").value;

and my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClientID = document.getElementById("ClientIDTextBox").value;
    if (ClientID == "") {
        alert("Please enter ClientID")
      }
</script>
```

please help me

Comment: maybe element with id `ClientIDTextBox` wasn't found?

Comment: Let me guess, you put this script before the element you're trying to get the ID of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely getting a runtime error because the call `document.getElementById` is returning `null`.  The attempt to get the property `value` on `null` leads to an error.

Try the following instead

```
var element = document.getElementById('ClientIDTextBox');
if (element) {
  var ClientID = element.value;
  ...
}
```

The root cause though is likely that your javascript is running before the DOM is loaded and hence your element with id `ClientIDTextBox` is not available.  Ensure your javascript runs after the DOM is loaded to prevent this problem.

Comment: Any logical reason why this is a bad answer? Why the downvote?

Comment: @Mike, my first version had `getElementById` returning `undefined` instead of `null` on error.  I've since corrected that but it could be the cause of the original downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ClientID = document.getElementById("ClientIDTextBox");
    if (ClientID == null || ClientID.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter ClientID")
      }
</script>
```